# Two aliases for one location nginx

Tags: django, nginx, alias

So I have settings (part of it) as follows:

```
location /static {
    alias /home/django/projectname/static;
}
location /static/admin {
   alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
}
```

I want to add something as follows:

```
location /static/admin/ {
  alias /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flat/static/admin/;
}
```

I would like to have 2 different aliases for 1 location (/static/admin/), so nginx searches in both of them if this location is in my url. What's the "nginx-way" for doing this?

I know about collectstatic (django command), but anyway I want to know how to solve this case.

Comment: I do not think you want to use an alias. Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15737782/1375015

Comment: You don't need to have 2 locations.  When you run `./manage.py collectstatic` Django will collect all static assets (including the django admin static files) into your `settings.STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: Please look at the last line of my question:
>I know about collectstatic (django command), but anyway I want to know how to solve this case.

This means I know about collectstatic and use it in production, but I still want an answer. I would like to use answer-technique sometimes during debug phase in production environment.